# Is it possible to create a program like Photoshop with C# WinForms?

Tags: wpf, winforms, performance, bitmap, photoshop

So I am wondering if, in term of performance, it's possible to create a graphic editor like Photoshop capable of handling bitmap graphics on layers (at least 25 layers). It also need to handle various type of brushes, copy paste graphics blocks, etc. Well, what Photoshop can do at the basic level.

Are WinForms capable of this without being slow? Or is WPF the only good alternative?

Comment: It is capable I guess, if you design it well and write good code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Paint.Net](http://getpaint.net) uses Winforms it is possible. You can check out the source code from this [fork of 3.36.7](http://code.google.com/p/openpdn/) (the last version where the source was released)